# Flask - Redirect to same page with lots of data from database

Tags: python, session, flask

I am building an application and below showing only relevant code to keep things simple. Basically I have form on "booksearch" route. Once user click submit button, I want to fetch all the books from database and show in the table underneath the form (on the same page). So, I have code as below:

```
from flask import Flask, request

@app.route('/booksearch', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def booksearch():
    if request.method == 'GET'
        render_template("booksearch.html")
        #If i use session then code is here to check if session['books'] has data and if yes then pass to the template
    else:
        # books = getting data from database
        render_template("booksearch.html", books = books)   #This displays data in table in jinja2 template, but have "Form Re-submission" problem
        # redirect(url_for('booksearch'))     # This will solve "Form Re-submission" problem, but can't send books data to jinja2 template to populate table in html
        # redirect(url_for('booksearch'), books=books)     #This will send data as url parameters, which I don't want and can't as data too much.

        # Another option to save data in Session and then redirect will work
        # session['books'] = books
        # redirect(url_for('booksearch'))
```

As you can see, if I use render_template again in POST then it works fine to display the data, by passing all the database data to jinja2 template and displaying in html table. But that will bring "Form Resubmission" issue on page refresh. 
If I use Post->Redirect->GET solution, then I am not able to pass data from database to the jinja2 template.
Other option then I have is to use SESSION and in POST method save data to session and then use that in GET part to send data to template. But problem is my data from database is a lot and session can store only limited (i think 4082 bytes), and moreover I have read that using sessions is not good approach.

I am sure this must be common problem, so I want to ask how you guys solve this issue and how you deal with it. Ofcourse I can use below solutions/workarounds, but want to check if these are only solutions:

1. Change my user experience and don't show table underneath form. Instead have totally new page for that. But this is not good approach from user perspective.
2. Use AJAX, and I can get data on button click via Ajax and load html table via Javascript.

Comment: Why are you submitting, when actually you want to fetch?

Comment: On /booksearch route, i have a form where user can search book with title or isbn. So that's why I need to submit it, and in same method under "POST", I am then fetching data from database for title/isbn, and then have to display all the books under the form as html table.